# Single word of "Senseless words"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I while back a heard a word that means 'senseless words'

It was used in the following context: "You are speaking in ... "

And the full phrase had the exact same meaning as "What you are saying is senseless" or "What you are saying makes no sense"

I know it ends with `cies`.

Note: It is not synonymous with foolish as far as I know

Comment: Are you looking for "***gibberish***"? Or, more mundane, simply "*nonsense*"?

Comment: Um... *nonsense", perhaps; or **gobbledygook**? I think we need a bit of a clue here.

Comment: @DanBron That could be it but unfortunately that was not the word.

Comment: @AndrewLeach "You are speaking in nonsense" Doesn't sound right

Comment: We don't go in for guessing games, I'm afraid. You've had three reasonable words which you might use to look up synonyms: please show your research.

Comment: @ViruZX Hmm, maybe check out some [**synonyms for *nonsense***](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/nonsense)? Or, could you perhaps be looking for the religiously-tinted "*speaking in **tongues***"?

Comment: @Andrew, I think closure is a bit premature. OP has demonstrated a willingness to engage in the comments, at least. And we put up with the guessing games around "*vignette*" for *hours* yesterday.

Comment: @DanBron I think the closure was justified. The only other 'clue' to this guessing game I can give is that it ends with 'cies' but that makes it sound even more like a guessing game does it not?

Comment: @DanBron It all depends on who is moderating when. I'm very happy to re-open this when it's improved. As for *vignette,* there was quite a bit of clearing up to do on that question.

Comment: @AndrewLeach How could I improve it?

Comment: @ViruZX (A) Do some research, using the suggestions so far, and show what you've found; (B) if you have a specific word or ending in mind, make sure the question includes it. Add a flag when [you're happy](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed). [It's midnight here; I'm off for eight hours or so]

Comment: @Viru, start by adding as much context and as many clues as you can, starting with the hint about *-cies*, and anything else your interlocutor said at the time, which much shed light. .... it isn't ***lunacies***, by any chance?

Comment: @DanBron No that seems to mean more 'foolish' than 'senseless'

Comment: @ViruZX Well, it means "*f£#%ing **nuts***", but if it's not the word you're looking for, then it's not the word you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe fallacies? From Wikipedia, *A fallacy is incorrect argument in logic and rhetoric resulting in a lack of validity, or more generally, a lack of soundness.*

Answer (score 1):

I would think ***idiocies*** would go here. It means

> foolishness or senselessness; stupidity; a foolish act or remark (Collins)

e.g.

> He was complaining again about the idiocies of the people he works for. ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiocy#:%7E:text=an%20act%20of%20sheer%20idiocy,the%20people%20he%20works%20for.))

The sentence you are looking for may be

> You are ***speaking idiocies***.

It is not a frequent expression, but it is colloquial. That's why it is rarely found in written texts.

e.g.

> Trondr, I called you here to offer me good suggestions, not to ***speak idiocies***. ([reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/HistoricalWorldPowers/comments/hl9crx/friction/))

> To ***speak idiocies*** to children but not to tell them truths, to say polite nothings to women but not truth... (quote attributed to [Nietzche - GBooks](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9RzI47bquWIC&pg=SA2-PA87&lpg=SA2-PA87&dq=%22speak%20idiocies%22&source=bl&ots=XUKBsGZ5bp&sig=ACfU3U3lb_eXH7tOgElmOyIWmjYb8fNe5A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYufvXzdruAhVIZxUIHXnJAasQ6AEwCHoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22speak%20idiocies%22&f=false))

I can't think of an expression that would include the preposition ***in*** here ("speaking in idiocies" doesn't seem right).

Answer (score 0):

The possible candidates I have identified (partly with the help of OneLook.com) are **conspiracies, fallacies/[pathetic fallacies](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/pathetic-fallacy), fancies, fantasies, idiosyncrasies, illiteracies, inconsistencies, lunacies** and **redundancies**; and some of those are pretty marginal possibilities at that.

If none of them ring a bell, then I think your memory is at fault.